# Finding maximum weighted n disjoint cliques

Tags: graphs, np-hard, clique

Maximum weight clique problem has some attention but i could not find any efficient approaches to this problem yet. I acknowledge that it is np-hard, but are there any known approximations?

Given a fixed n and an undirected graph, the problem can be defined as finding n disjoint cliques which maximize the sum of the vertex weights in these cliques. Disjoint cliques can be defined as cliques that do not have any common vertex.

I have taken a look on [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1419/b8187870646bb52e2f1cc5859e18959e5d47.pdf) dissertation but did not help much.